# How to get MIME type of uploaded file in Jersey

Tags: java, file-upload, upload, mime-types, jersey

I have a standard upload endpoint in Jersey:

```
@POST
@Secure
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response upload( @Context final HttpHeaders hh,
            @FormDataParam("fileaaa") final FormDataContentDisposition disposition,
            @FormDataParam("fileaaa") final InputStream input,
```

How can I get the MIME type of the uploaded file?

If I do `disposition.getType` this gets me the MIME type of the form; in this case `form-data`.

I know the information is there somewhere; the HTTP message should be something like:

```
-----------------------------7d01ecf406a6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input_text"

mytext

-----------------------------7d01ecf406a6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileaaa";
filename="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Upload\pic.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif

(binary content)
-----------------------------7d01ecf406a6--
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I solved this by letting Jersey inject a [BodyPart](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.16/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/BodyPart.html) parameter in my method. getMediaType() on the body part gives me what I needed:

```
@POST
@Secure
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(/*other parms */,  @FormDataParam("fileaaa") final FormDataBodyPart body) {
   String mimeType = body.getMediaType().toString();
   //handle upload
}
```

Comment: Resurrecting a dead question here, but how did you do this?  I'm encountering the same issue (was trying to use URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream but it seems to fail on text files), and when I add an injected param of the form [@FormDataParam("my_file") BodyPart body], it just gets set to null.

Comment: @Arkaaito I haven't touched this in a while, but have you looked at MultiPart parameters for your endpoint? You don't need to prefix it with FormDataParam and you can get the body parts from that.

Comment: BigRedBettaFish's comment: "Just a note to the accepted answer, to get the BodyPart, you can use:
`@FormDataParam("my_file") FormDataBodyPart body`
Then you can use `body.getMediaType()`"

Comment: Link in answer is broken.

Comment: @mdw7326 Yeah, the answer is really old, they changed the location of Jersey JavaDoc since then. I updated to a more recent one.

Comment: What does `*/*` mean in mimeType?