# What does the @Secure annotation do and what package is it apart of

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, java-ee-6, security-context

I'm writing an API using Java EE, JAX-RS, Jersey. In doing this I've implemented my own security context and security filter.

Looking at questions like this one ([How to get MIME type of uploaded file in Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157127/how-to-get-mime-type-of-uploaded-file-in-jersey)) I've seen the @Secure annotation but what does it do? My hope was that is was an annotation that queries the isSecure method of the security context in the same way that @RolesAllowed does for checking if a user has the right to access a particular method. If so is there such a way of doing so with annotations or am I stuck to using the @Context to get the security context and just from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Secure` annotation seems to be a custom one. JAX-RS/Jersey does not support such feature out-of-the-box but it's not that hard to implement. Lets say you have your own `@Secure` annotation and you want to do checks whether a communication channel is secure for methods annotated with this annotation. You need to create a custom [ResourceFilterFactory](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ResourceFilterFactory.html) in which you'll assign a special filter for such methods:

```
public class IsSecureResourceFilterFactory implements ResourceFilterFactory {

    private class IsSecureFilter implements ResourceFilter, ContainerRequestFilter {

        // ResourceFilter

        @Override
        public ContainerRequestFilter getRequestFilter() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public ContainerResponseFilter getResponseFilter() {
            return null;
        }

        // ContainerRequestFilter

        @Override
        public ContainerRequest filter(final ContainerRequest request) {
            // Check whether the channel is secure.
            if (request.isSecure()) {
                return request;
            }

            // Throw an exception if it's not.
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<ResourceFilter> create(final AbstractMethod abstractMethod) {
        // Add IsSecureFilter for resource methods annotated with @Secure annotation (ignore other resource methods).
        return abstractMethod.isAnnotationPresent(Secure.class)
                ? Collections.<ResourceFilter>singletonList(new IsSecureFilter()): null;
    }
}
```

Now you need to tell Jersey about this `ResourceFilterFactory`. There are 2 ways:

- via `web.xml`

  ```
  <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
      <param-value>my.package.IsSecureResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
  </init-param>
  ```
- or via `META-INF/services` mechanism - you need to create a file called `META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilterFactory` which would contain a fully qualified name of your factory (in this case `my.package.IsSecureResourceFilterFactory`) and make sure this file is on the class-path of your application.